# How to reference 'this' inside an interface listener implemented with NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript

In Java, I have the documentation for the following code:

```java
import com.creator.creatorandroidsdk.terminal.DeviceSelectionListener
import com.creator.creatorandroidsdk.TerminalListManager;

public class ConfigPinPadActivity extends Activity implements DeviceSelectionListener {

        TerminalListManager terminalListManager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            terminalListManager = new TerminalListManager(this,getApplicationContext());
            terminalListManager.startTerminalsDiscovery();
        }

//...

}
```

Where `this` is sent to a class method as a reference to the instance of the implementation itself:

```java
terminalListManager = new TerminalListManager(this,getApplicationContext());
```

I've tryied to replicate the code in NativeScript, but the reference doesn't work:

```js
const { DeviceSelectionListener } = com.creator.creatorandroidsdk.terminal
const { TerminalListManager } = com.creator.creatorandroidsdk

const superProto = androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.prototype

androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.extend(
  'com.company.configPinPadActivity',
  {
    interfaces: [DeviceSelectionListener],
    terminalListManager: {},
    onCreate: function (savedInstanceState) {

      console.log('OnCreated fired') // <- It works.
      this.terminalListManager = new TerminalListManager(this, utilsModule.ad.getApplicationContext())
```

This particular error comes up.

```
JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to pass an instance of com.company.configPinPadActivity as argument 1 to void com.creator.creatorandroidsdk.TerminalListManager.<init>(com.creator.creatorandroidsdk.terminal.DeviceSelectionListener, android.content.Context)

JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: bad arguments passed to void com.creator.creatorandroidsdk.TerminalListManager.<init>(com.creator.creatorandroidsdk.terminal.DeviceSelectionListener, android.content.Context) (see above for details)
```

I'm really trying to pass an instance of `com.company.configPinPadActivity` implementation to the `new TerminalListManager`, and since the `com.company.configPinPadActivity` implements a `DeviceSelectionListener`, I cannot understand why this isn't working.

How can reference the instance of the implementation from within the implementation itself?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are confusing TerminalListManager to being an interface. You cannot instantiate interfaces (new TerminalListManager), only implementations of such interfaces.

Would help if you add the source of TerminalListManager. If you are trying to pass 'this' to the TerminalListManager constructor, you need to have the the type of first parameter ConfigPinPadActivity (or Activity if you plan to re-use the TerminalListManager) or of type `DeviceSelectionListener`.

Comment: Before anything else, that was fast. Like Usain Bolt fast. Seriously, I am amazed.

The TerminalListManager accepts two arguments. The first seems to be the problem:

The first one is described as `pDeviceSelectionListener`. I can access its class by going to `com.creator.creatorandroidsdk.terminal.DeviceSelectionListener`. 

Unfortunately, this class is compiled ( a `.class` file ).

Comment: I think that is important to mention that the documentation in Java is provided by the person who makes the interface. I am assuming that the Java code is correct.

Comment: what is the import statement for DeviceSelectionListener? it should be: `com.creator.creatorandroidsdk.terminal.DeviceSelectionListener`

Comment: I have updated the code with the import statements.

Comment: Is the Java code working? (it should) If so the problem is only with the NativeScript code then..I don't have any experience with it.