# Implementation angular plugin to nativescript-vue

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am newbie with nativescipt-vue. I need to connect identity server with nativescript-vue. I found a plugin in this [repo](https://github.com/EdSaleh/oauth2-oidc-client). But its developer gives only angular example. Can I use this plugin with nativescript-vue. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, you must be able to use it Vue. There is no Angular specific code within the plugin. But FYI, it uses an outdated version of RxJS. If you are concerned about that, then you may just copy the service file to your project and adjust it with latest RxJS library.

Answer (score 0):

**Good news**: Most of 'things' developed on the top of NativeScript are interoperable, meaning that you can swap frameworks as desired.

**Bad news**: There is some problems of doing so. I've looked into the repository that you reported on the question and I saw that you have to deal with some `Interfaces` there.

```
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit { //...
```

Dealing with interfaces in NativeScript is a little bit confusing since you have to deal with classes in both NativeScript and Java in the same script.

The lack of documented behavior of `this` keyword, for example, can lead to some undesired behaviors. [I am dealing with this problem right now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57929536/how-to-reference-this-inside-an-interface-listener-implemented-with-nativescri). So, be careful.

Please provide us some parts of the code that you want to transpile to NativeScript-Vue.

Also, **I highly recommend you to study how NativeScript works before understanding how NativeScript-Vue works**. You are probably accessing the NS docs way more than NativeScript-Vue docs in a near future (assuming that you are already familiar with Vue).